# Permission difference with scp "dir -r", "dir/*", and "dir/file.txt"

Tags: scp

Recently I have been getting an error when trying to `scp` into a **CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908** (3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64).

These commands work:

- `scp dir/file.txt .`
- `scp -r dir/file.txt .`

But this command has stopped working:

- `scp dir/* .`

The error is:

```
insecure scp option not allowed.
This account is restricted by rssh.
Allowed commands: scp
```

What is the permission difference between using a star and just copying the whole directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to use a glob (*) on the remote directory, you must escape it with backslash first. Otherwise your local shell is going to expand it. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27419/how-to-use-wildcards-when-copying-with-scp) for a more in-depth discussion.